# primary attribute not allowed inside bean tag

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have tried to set the default validation message file to messages.properties file. It worked. However, for some reason the primary attribute inside validator bean is marked red in the applicationContext.xml file.

The error message, "Attribute primary is not allowed here".

I have tried to find the reason of this in many resources and cross-checked many possibilities, but everything seems fine with my configuration.

I use Intellij Idea, Spring version - 3.2.17 RELEASE, Hibernate version - 3.6.10.Final.

Can anyone explain the reason ?

applicationContext.xml -

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.leavemanagement"/>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" primary="true">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: primary="true" it seems you're not allowed to put that

Comment: but it works on my another project and does not give this message. And now it is working on my new project but shows a red flag. Can't seem to find the reason why! @Stultuske